# How to compile application with Visual Studio 2008 in Windows XP for Windows 98 SE

Tags: windows-xp, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, windows-98

I have Visual C++ 2008 installed in Windows XP. Compiled applications doesn't work in Windows 98 SE. How do I configure my compiler that it compiles Windows 98 compliant applications in Windows XP?

**Extra question:**

If it is not possible in Visual C++ 2008, how can I achieve the same in older Visual C++ releases?

Comment: I think you have compile the application for the multi-byte character set (MBCS). It will not work when compiled as Unicode.

Comment: The simplest way would be to use a non-Microsoft C++ compiler. There is no way to get `Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable` to work on `Windows 98 SE`.  This also applies to any of the more recent versions of the Visual C++ redistributable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're going to have to revert to [Visual Studio 6.0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio).  I'd be surprised if you can find a copy to use.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 is designed for all .net products upto .net 3.5. If you are compiling your product to a .net 3.5 application, then it will not work in Windows 98 SE since Win 98 SE supports only .net 1.0 and 1.1

Comment: thanks. how do i make VS to compile specific .net version application?

Comment: In the solution explorer of visual studio, you can find out the properties option of your project. Open the properties. There you can find out the target framework to which the current project needs to be built.

Comment: i can not change target framework version. it is set to .net 3.5. why?